# Flask not receiving POST blob from HTML POST

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask, speech-recognition

Flast is receiving ImmutableMultiDict([]).

My Html Code

```
const audioChunks = [];
            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", event => {
                audioChunks.push(event.data);
            });

            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", () => {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(audioChunks, { type: 'audio/wav' });
                console.log(audioBlob)
                var myHeaders = new Headers();
                myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "audio/wave");
                var requestOptions = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: myHeaders,
                    body: audioBlob,
                    redirect: 'follow'
                };
```

My Flask Code

```
@app.route('/stt',methods=['GET','POST'])
def STT():
    app.logger.warning("request.files: {0}".format(request.files))
    f = request.files['audio-blob']
    print(f)
    file_obj = io.BytesIO()  # create file-object
    file_obj.write(f.read())  # write in file-object
    file_obj.seek(0)  # move to beginning so it will read from beginning
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    mic = sr.AudioFile(file_obj)  # use file-object
    with mic as source:
        audio = r.record(source)

    result = r.recognize_google(audio_data=audio, language="en-US", show_all=True)
    return jsonify(text=result )
```

Not able to understand the error.
How to post Blob file from html and received in Flask Post APIs.
Please Help me out on this problem.

Thank You

Comment: You seem to upload the data as the body, not as a file att attachment.

Comment: @KlausD. its receiving Bytes in flask api rather than .wav file.

Comment: The bytes are the `.wav` file!

Comment: @KlausD.But i am getting the error `wave.Error: file does not start with RIFF id` and `ValueError: Audio file could not be read as PCM WAV, AIFF/AIFF-C, or Native FLAC; check if file is corrupted or in another format`. can you please help me out on this